# How can I calculate the quotient from the same column of two seperate rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the folowing table `test`:

```
MonthNumber    Fees      FeesName
1              10        A
2              22        A
3              25        A
1              11        B
2              25        B
3              28        B
3              8         C
3              2         D
3              3         E
```

I am looking `Fees(A) / Fees(B)`, for each `MonthNumber`.

Comment: have you tried it yourself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Pivot:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT MonthNumber, Fees, Feesname 
  FROM test
  WHERE FeesName in ('A', 'B')
) 
SELECT MonthNumber, [A]/[B]
FROM  cte
PIVOT (SUM(Fees) FOR [Feesname] IN ([A], [B])) AS pvt 
ORDER BY MonthNumber
```

And if you don't like pivot or use an sqlserver 2005 or older

```
SELECT 
  MonthNumber, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN FeesName = 'A' THEN Fees END)/
  SUM(CASE WHEN FeesName = 'B' THEN Fees END) result
FROM test
WHERE FeesName in ('A', 'B')
GROUP BY MonthNumber
ORDER BY MonthNumber
```

Comment: +1. If you want to perform floating point division, you may want to cast `Fees` as `FLOAT` or just multiply one of the operand to `1.0`, that is `Fees * 1.0`

Comment: @wewesthemenace yes, I was considering that as well. But then i decided to stick to what was given, which wasn't much.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is pretty sparse, but if I'm understanding you correctly, then you want something like this:

```
SELECT A.Fees / B.Fees
FROM test A
    INNER JOIN test B ON A.MonthNumber = B.MonthNumber
WHERE A.FeesName = 'A' AND B.FeesName = 'B'
```

Basically, join the table against itself and run your division as you generally would.